# How to display formatted Jupyter stack trace from "full output data"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, jupyter, stack-trace

I am debugging Python code in VS Code using the Jupyter integration in interactive mode.

The stack trace I get is only partially displayed, because "Output exceeds the *size limit*." I would like to see the full stack trace.

I'm advised to "Open the full output data *in a text editor*".

When I do that, by clicking on "in a text editor" I get something that looks like JSON but is too messy for human consumption:

```json
{
    "name": "InvalidOperationError",
    "message": "window expression not allowed in aggregation",
    "stack": "\u001b[0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31mInvalidOperationError\u001b[0m                     Traceback (most recent call last)\n\u001b[1;32m/Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36mline 2\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=38'>39</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39m#%%\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m----> <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=39'>40</a>\u001b[0m df\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mwith_columns(\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=40'>41</a>\u001b[0m     [\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=41'>42</a>\u001b[0m         pl\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mstruct(\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=42'>43</a>\u001b[0m             [\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=43'>44</a>\u001b[0m                 (\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=44'>45</a>\u001b[0m                     pl\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mcol(specs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39myvar\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m])\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=45'>46</a>\u001b[0m                     \u001b[39m-\u001b[39;49m pl\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mcol(specs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39myvar\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m])\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mmean()\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mover(specs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mgvars\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m])\n\u001b[1;32m      <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=46'>47</a>\u001b[0m                 )\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mabs(),\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=47'>48</a>\u001b[0m                 \u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49mspecs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mxvars\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m],\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=48'>49</a>\u001b[0m             ]\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=49'>50</a>\u001b[0m         )\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=50'>51</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mapply(\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=51'>52</a>\u001b[0m             partial(\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=52'>53</a>\u001b[0m                 ols_fitted, yvar\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mspecs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39myvar\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m], xvars\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49mspecs[specnm][\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mxvars\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m]\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=53'>54</a>\u001b[0m             )\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=54'>55</a>\u001b[0m         )\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=55'>56</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mover([\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mdate\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m, \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mid\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m])\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=56'>57</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49malias(\u001b[39mf\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mfitted_\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;49;00mspecnm\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;49;00m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m)\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=57'>58</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mfor\u001b[39;49;00m specnm \u001b[39min\u001b[39;49;00m \u001b[39mlist\u001b[39;49m(specs\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mkeys())\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=58'>59</a>\u001b[0m     ]\n\u001b[1;32m     <a href='file:///Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/tmp/so.py?line=59'>60</a>\u001b[0m )\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py:6139\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mDataFrame.with_columns\u001b[0;34m(self, exprs, *more_exprs, **named_exprs)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5985'>5986</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39mdef\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mwith_columns\u001b[39m(\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5986'>5987</a>\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mself\u001b[39m,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5987'>5988</a>\u001b[0m     exprs: IntoExpr \u001b[39m|\u001b[39m Iterable[IntoExpr] \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mNone\u001b[39;00m,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5988'>5989</a>\u001b[0m     \u001b[39m*\u001b[39mmore_exprs: IntoExpr,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5989'>5990</a>\u001b[0m     \u001b[39m*\u001b[39m\u001b[39m*\u001b[39mnamed_exprs: IntoExpr,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5990'>5991</a>\u001b[0m ) \u001b[39m-\u001b[39m\u001b[39m>\u001b[39m Self:\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5991'>5992</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    \u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5992'>5993</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    Add columns to this DataFrame.\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=5993'>5994</a>\u001b[0m \n\u001b[0;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6133'>6134</a>\u001b[0m \n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6134'>6135</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    \"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6135'>6136</a>\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mself\u001b[39m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39m_from_pydf(\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6136'>6137</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mlazy()\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6137'>6138</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mwith_columns(exprs, \u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49mmore_exprs, \u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m*\u001b[39;49mnamed_exprs)\n\u001b[0;32m-> <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6138'>6139</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mcollect(no_optimization\u001b[39m=\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mTrue\u001b[39;49;00m)\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6139'>6140</a>\u001b[0m         \u001b[39m.\u001b[39m_df\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py?line=6140'>6141</a>\u001b[0m     )\n\nFile \u001b[0;32m/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py:1323\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mLazyFrame.collect\u001b[0;34m(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, common_subplan_elimination, streaming)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1311'>1312</a>\u001b[0m     common_subplan_elimination \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mFalse\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1313'>1314</a>\u001b[0m ldf \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mself\u001b[39m\u001b[39m.\u001b[39m_ldf\u001b[39m.\u001b[39moptimization_toggle(\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1314'>1315</a>\u001b[0m     type_coercion,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1315'>1316</a>\u001b[0m     predicate_pushdown,\n\u001b[0;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1320'>1321</a>\u001b[0m     streaming,\n\u001b[1;32m   <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1321'>1322</a>\u001b[0m )\n\u001b[0;32m-> <a href='file:///opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py?line=1322'>1323</a>\u001b[0m \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m pli\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mwrap_df(ldf\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mcollect())\n\n\u001b[0;31mInvalidOperationError\u001b[0m: window expression not allowed in aggregation"
}
```

How can I display the `stack` variable in a nicely formatted manner, similar to how the excerpt is shown in the image below?

[image: How the excerpt is shown, nicely formatted]

Is there maybe a VS code extension for this? Or does the value of the `stack` key look like some known formatting? Is this using ANSI escapes or something else that I could use a CLI tool for viewing?

Comment: Related: [VS Code text output unreadable format in new window](/q/71195740/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

A more concise traceback, often sufficient, can be obtained by wrapping the raising code in a try/except and printing the stack trace using `traceback`, e.g.:

```py
import traceback
try:
    [].pop()  # replace this line with your erroring code
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

For the example given above, the stack trace becomes *much* more readable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-ce1246cd962c>", line 4, in <module>
    df.with_columns(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 6139, in with_columns
    .collect(no_optimization=True)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1323, in collect
    return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
exceptions.InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153855).

The terminal knows how to format the `stack` string correctly. So one can copy the whole thing and paste it into the terminal, prefixing with `echo -e`.

Or one save the file and runs the following to automate the JSON value extraction:

```bash
jj stack <tmp.json | less -R
```

The result is still not ideal and could benefit from some post-processing, filtering out the long `<a href>`s but it's better than the unformatted:

[image]

The advantage of using `less` is that lines don't necessarily wrap. If you use plain terminal output, the long lines will wrap making things unreadable.

[image]

One can also increase the value of `notebook.output.textLineLimit` in VS Code settings.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT thanks for the reminder :) I will consciously refrain from accepting an answer at the moment, because neither of the two answers are fully satisfactory in my view. Either of them are somewhat ok as workarounds, depending on user preference.